# appium selects incorrect item from the popup list

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

I have two questions related to the same issue that I cannot solve. I'm creating an appium programm to test a native android app. I'm using Java. 
Before the login, there's an option in the app to change the environment. I'm passing in my appium class the environment name as a parameter, and I'm using the Xpath to find the element corresponding to the provided environment.
Issue: it doesn't matter which environment name I'm passing as a parameter, every time it changes to the particular one (staging). 
Questions:

1. What could be the cause of it?
2. Why when I'm using the xpath with the text parameter, the appium cannot find the element despite the uiautomatorviewer tool has that text property.

   selectEnv = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@text='QA']"));

I provided 2 screenshots. The first one is an actual app screen with the list of the environments and the properties from Android Studio Layout Inspector. 
[image]

The second one is the screenshot of uiautomatorviewer properties for one of the items from the list. 
[image]

```
new WebDriverWait(androidDriver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(id("md_contentRecyclerView")));
        envContainer = androidDriver.findElement(By.id("md_contentRecyclerView"));
        Assert.assertTrue(envContainer.isDisplayed());
        if (env.equals("dev")) {
            selectEnv = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']"));
            selectEnv.click();
        }
        if (env.equals("QA")) {
            selectEnv = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index = '1']"));
            selectEnv.click();
        }
        if (env.equals("Staging")) {
            selectEnv = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='2']"));
            selectEnv.click();
        }
        if (env.equals("Prod")) {
            selectEnv = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='3']"));
            selectEnv.click();
        }
```

Comment: did you try to select it with an ID instead of the text value

Comment: unfortunately there are no ids for those particular elements

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to click the LinearLayout instead of its Textview.

Use:

```
selectEnv = androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(.,'QA')]"));
selectEnv.click();
```

Comment: The code didn't work for me, but you pointed to a right thing: after I used TextView instead of LinearLayout I was able to google the extra steps and now everything works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, at least.  Could you upvote my answer since it was useful?  You should mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I just realized my answer should NOT have had an at sign in front of `contains` and I had the wrong case for "TextView" I fixed both (It's Friday)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually was able to find the element using UiSelector

```
findElementByAndroidUIAutomator ("new UiSelector().textContains(\"QA\")");
```